# Modify Yourls Bookmarklet add function

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I try to do in Yourls official bookmarklet a modification but don't work, i am sure is a stupid thing, but i have limited knowledge.

The code is:

```
javascript:(function(){ var d=document, sc=d.createElement('script'), l=d.location.href, enc=encodeURIComponent, ups=l.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9\+\.-]+:(\/\/)?/)[0], ur=l.split(new RegExp(ups))[1], ups=ups.split(/\:/), p='?up='+enc(ups[0]+':')+'&us='+enc(ups[1])+'&ur='+enc(ur)+'&t='+enc(d.title); window.yourls_callback=function(r){ if(r.short_url){ prompt(r.message,r.short_url);}else{ alert('An error occured: '+r.message);}}; sc.src='https://xxxxxxxxx.com/xxx/admin/index.php'+p+'&jsonp=yourls'; void(d.body.appendChild(sc));})();
```

I want to modify the url get from the browser adding a previous code, like this:

```
javascript:(function(){ var d=document, sc=d.createElement('script'), l='https://xxxxxxxxxxxx'+d.location.href, enc=encodeURIComponent, ups=l.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9\+\.-]+:(\/\/)?/)[0], ur=l.split(new RegExp(ups))[1], ups=ups.split(/\:/), p='?up='+enc(ups[0]+':')+'&us='+enc(ups[1])+'&ur='+enc(ur)+'&t='+enc(d.title); window.yourls_callback=function(r){ if(r.short_url){ prompt(r.message,r.short_url);}else{ alert('An error occured: '+r.message);}}; sc.src='https://xxxxxxxxx.com/xxx/admin/index.php'+p+'&jsonp=yourls'; void(d.body.appendChild(sc));})();
```

replaced 
l=d.location.href
to
l='https://xxxxxxxxxxxx'+d.location.href

But the url that arrives to YOURLS is only https://xxxxxxxxxxxx the +d.location.href is not added.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I think I might understand what you’re asking, but instead of using https://xxxxxxxxxxxx, please format your question with a clearer example. Maybe: “the URL I want to add is https://example.com/secret-address.php?action=more-secrets, but when I code as I modified it, YOURLS.org is using only https://example.com/secret-address.php”.

Comment: Thanks,  the injected URL is something is this:

`code 'https://test.sample.com/link.php?number=9999&url='+d.location.href `

Result in plain text:

`code https://test.sample.com/link.php?number=9999&url=https://url.website.com/sub/main `

I think the problem is the two https in the same line

Comment: I created a local installation of Yourls to track down the problem. I’m pretty sure you’re running in to the the parser’s inability to properly escape URIs. It’s a bug the software has had since its inception, and which, as of 2019, has been [a known issue for over 6 years](https://github.com/YOURLS/YOURLS/issues/1303). I recommend you use a different URL shortener.